# Facebook app id for website social plugins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have like/share buttons on my website and am not currently using an appid. Finding information on whether this is a necessity for the above configuration is difficult to confirm. When going through the Facebook app "create" forms, I'm really confused by a lot of the requirements as it seems to be more focused around actual apps rather than websites, which login via fb etc.

1. In the past I have created an app for one of my other websites and I don't believe there was any verification/submission process at this point (about 2-3 years ago). Reviewing my old app configuration now I can see that it is not "live" - does anyone know whether Facebook implemented this submission process in the last couple of years, and then de-activated any live apps that were created prior to this?
2. I now want to setup a new app for my new website and I'm unsure what the different 'action types' mean and what I would need to simply use like/share buttons on the website. Could someone give me a quick run down of what I'd need and what they are?

Any other info/tips people can provide would be greatly appreciated. I'm finding that the like/share DO still work without the app, but sometimes the share button doesn't work properly (I have a feeling this is something to do with the app).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using the Social Plugins, you *don't need* to have a Facebook App ID.

If you want more integration, it will be required. Creating an App ID is like registering your App, wether an iOS or Android App or just a website, so that you can make Graph API calls for it.

The easiest way to register your website is to go the quickstart: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=web (or https://developers.facebook.com/apps). There you can type a name and follow the steps.

You can then follow the "Sharing best practices" (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags) on how to use the App ID. For example, by including an `fb:app_id` meta tag on your pages.

There is a review process, since last April, but that is only needed if you use permissions for your App. If you just use the plugins, that is not needed.

Can you explain more what is exactly not working?

**Update**
The time you create a page the Facebook crawler does not know yet what the Opengraph data for that one is. This will happen after the first share, but if you want to ensure it is correct from the first share on, you can force a re-scrape.

This section explains how that works:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

> When an app triggers a scrape using an API endpoint This Graph API
>   endpoint is simply a call to:
>
> POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true

Comment: Thanks for your clarification Flaxfield. It seemed there was an issue picking up the open graph information at times. Mainly when it was the first time sharing something, but after it was shared it seemed to work ok - felt like some sort of cache issue.

Comment: I have also noticed a massive drop off in the link clicks to page views ratio. We use to commonly experience approx 3 page views on site for every FB link click however this is a lot closer to 1:1 now. I know some other people who are still getting a 3:1 ratio. I had hoped this might have been related to not using an appid correctly but doesnt appear to be. Any ideas other than "facebook algo change"?

Comment: @Sami.C, I've updated my answer to include information about the first share. If you still have issue, you need to be more specific than "issues picking up"; it's hard to understand what exactly is not working to your expectation.

Comment: I have two questions/concerns which I'll put in separate comments. 

1. It's interesting that you say that it will not scrape until the first share, because this seems to have only been an issue since moving to a new website. Previously during the "act of" sharing the page the first time, the open graph image, title etc were all successfully loaded. It now seems we have to share it once, then on the 2nd time it loads all open graph correctly. Previously this would work ok on the original share

Comment: 2. Are you able to comment on my link click to page view ratio that I mentioned? I had originally thought these two were inter-related, perhaps something to do with an appid. Whenever questions like this are thrown around people default to the typical "fb algo update" response. I previously was obtaining (regularly) approx 3 page views per link click. It's been about 1:1 for 12 months now - I thought this must be an algo update, but then speaking with some others they do still receive this 3:1. Please note this is on large scale with viral content only.

Comment: This is not accurate or is no longer accurate. The FAQs seem pretty clear on this. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs